# Native android background module for react native

Tags: android, react-native

I want to write a android native module which work as a background service and get current location and post to server and then integrate that module with react native.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question is very broad and not something that someone could easily help you with.  Here's a guide for asking questions that may help you get a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I would start here for native modules: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android

Answer (score 0):

if you just want it for the location then i suggest [react-native-workers](https://github.com/devfd/react-native-workers)
 it has access to native modules (network, geolocation, storage ...) you can aslo integrate it with [react-native-queue](https://github.com/billmalarky/react-native-queue)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of example projects / demo apps you might want to check out which implement both "Foreground Services" and "Background Services" in Android to help you get location updates while the app is closed or the screen is off. The background service example will only allow you to get updates as frequent as 1 minute, while the foreground service example will allow you to get updates as fast as 1 second (or maybe faster, I haven't tested that yet) while also displaying an "Ongoing Notification" to the user.

- Background Service Example: https://github.com/comoser/rn-background-location
- Foreground Service Example: https://github.com/andersryanc/ReactNative-LocationSample

There are a number of Android specific code adjustments you will need to make in either case. It's not ready yet, but in the near future I plan to update my repo's readme with a detailed set of instructions for implementing the necessary changes in your project.